# Automate the Boring Stuff - Collatz Exercise

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, collatz-sequence

I wrote the following code for [the Collatz exercise: *The Collatz Sequence*](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/#calibre_link-2229)

Any feedback is appreciated.

> Write a function named `collatz()` that has one parameter named `number`. If `number` is even, then `collatz()` should print `number // 2` and return this value. If `number` is odd, then `collatz()` should print and return `3 * number + 1`.

```
def collatz(n):
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = int(n // 2)
            print (n)
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            n = int(3 * n + 1)
            print (n)

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
collatz (n)
```

Comment: @drapozo It would be welcome if you'd provide either a link or a small description of the problem.

Comment: It´s a problem form the Book automate the boring stuff with python. The problem is "The Collatz Sequence" and can be found in this link. https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/

Comment: When adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. I have added that information to your post. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

A few simple observations:

- > ```
  >     if n % 2 == 0:
  >         ...
  >     elif n % 2 == 1:
  >         ...
  > ```

  Here, we know that if `n % 2` isn't 0, it *must* be 1, since `n` is an integer.  So that `elif` can be simply `else`, making it simpler to read.  More experienced programmers will reverse the test, knowing that `1` is the only truthy result of `n % 2`, so write `if n % 2: ... ; else ...`.
- > ```
  >     if ...:
  >         ...
  >         print (n)
  >     else:
  >         ...
  >         print (n)
  > ```

  The `print` that's present in both branches could be placed after the `if`/`else`, since it doesn't depend on the condition.
- The results of the arithmetic expressions are already `int`, so no conversion is necessary.
- The `if`/`else` could be reduced to a single line:

  ```
  n = 3 * n + 1 if n % 2 else n // 2
  ```

  but to me, that looks less clear, so I don't recommend that level of terseness here.

---

## Modified code

Applying the observations above, I get a simpler version of the function:

```
def collatz(n):
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n = n // 2
        print(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your observations. In the simpler version you wrote i think you meant if n % 2 == 1.

Comment: No, I didn't mean `if n % 2 == 1`.  Because `n % 2` can only be 0 or 1, it's simpler to just test whether `n % 2` is truthy.

Comment: I think these are all good suggestions. For what it's worth though, I find the original if statements easier to read.